# Is it possible to use Netty in full duplex TCP communication?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, netty

It seems that Netty can only process either read or write operations with a single TCP connection, but not both at the same time. I have a client which connects to the echo server application that is written with Netty and sends about 200k messages.

The echo server simply accepts client connections and sends back any messages that are sent by the clients.

The problem is I can't make Netty work with the TCP connection in the full-duplex mode. I'd like to process read and write operations on the server side simultaneously. In my case Netty reads all messages from the client and then sends them back which is resulting with a high latency.

The client application fires two threads per connection. One for any write operations and the other one for read operations. And yes, the client is written in the plain old Java IO style.

Maybe the problem is somehow related to the TCP options which I set on the server side:

```
    .childOption(ChannelOption.ALLOCATOR, PooledByteBufAllocator.DEFAULT)
    .childOption(ChannelOption.WRITE_BUFFER_HIGH_WATER_MARK, bufferWatermarkHigh)
    .childOption(ChannelOption.WRITE_BUFFER_LOW_WATER_MARK, bufferWatermarkLow)
    .childOption(ChannelOption.SO_RCVBUF, bufferInSize)
    .childOption(ChannelOption.SO_SNDBUF, bufferOutSize)
    .childOption(ChannelOption.SO_REUSEADDR, true)
    .childOption(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true)
    .childOption(ChannelOption.TCP_NODELAY, true);
```

Comment: How does the code work on the server side? Can you provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem of not writing and reading at the same time? All my tests failed reproducing the issue you have.

Comment: TCP is full-duplex. Netty is full-duplex. Your question has a poorly chosen title and lacks the code concerned.

Comment: @EJP You know what? Why being so rude in the first place? What I was trying to ask if there is any way to process one client connection in at least two threads. One for read operations and another one for write operations. It turned out that since Netty 4.x you can't do that because this solution isn't scalable and difficult to reason about. And yes, I'm aware of TCP being full duplex. If you look at the Netty thread model you can see that an IO thread can process multiple client connections (read/write), but one client connection can be processed by only one thread.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the example you provided using the github repo, there are multiple wrong things:

- **You write directly from the `channelActive` method**

  In netty, there is a policy that every handler has only one incoming method executed at the same time, this is to make development easier, and to make sure methods of the class are executed in the correct order, it also does this to make sure the side effects of methods are visible in other classes.

  - **You are printing out the messages in `channelReadComplete`**

  `channelReadComplete` is called after the current buffer of messages is cleared, `channelRead` may be called multiple times before it is called.

  - **Missing a framer**

  Framing the messages or counting the size of messages is the way to detect how much bytes are coming inside. For 2 writes at the client may be 1 read at the server without this framer, as testing, I used a `new io.netty.handler.codec.FixedLengthFrameDecoder(120)`, so I could count using `i++` the amount of messages arrived at the server and client.
- **Using heavy weight printing for a lightweight operation.

  According to my profiler, most of the time spent was at the call `LOG.info()`, this is generaly the case with loggers as they do much behind the scenes, like synchronization at the output stream. By making the logger log only every 1000ste message, I got a huge speed increase (and a really slow computer since I run on dual core...)
- **Heavy sending code**

  The sending code recreates the `ByteBuf` every time again. By reusing the `ByteBuf` you can improve the sending speed even more, you can do this by creating the ByteBuf 1 time, and then calling `.retain()` on it every time you pass it.

  This is easily done by:

  ```
  ByteBuf buf = createMessage(MESSAGE_SIZE);
  for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_MESSAGES; ++i) {
      ctx.writeAndFlush(buf.retain());
  }
  ```
- **Reducing the amount of flushes**

  By reducing the amount of flushes, you can get higher native performance. Every call to flush() is a call to the network stack to send out pending messages. If we apply that rule to the code above it will give the following code:

  ```
  ByteBuf buf = createMessage(MESSAGE_SIZE);
  for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_MESSAGES; ++i) {
      ctx.write(buf.retain());
  }
  ctx.flush();
  ```

### Final code

Sometimes, you just want to see the result and try it for yourself instead:

**App.java (unchanged)**

```
public class App {
  public static void main( String[] args ) throws InterruptedException {
    final int PORT = 8080;
    runInSeparateThread(() -> new Server(PORT));
    runInSeparateThread(() -> new Client(PORT));
  }
  private static void runInSeparateThread(Runnable runnable) {
    new Thread(runnable).start();
  }
}
```

**Client.java**

```
public class Client {
  public Client(int port) {
    EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();
    try {
      ChannelFuture channelFuture = createBootstrap(group).connect("192.168.171.102", port).sync();
      channelFuture.channel().closeFuture().sync();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
      group.shutdownGracefully();
    }
  }
  private Bootstrap createBootstrap(EventLoopGroup group) {
    return new Bootstrap().group(group)
        .channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
        .option(ChannelOption.TCP_NODELAY, true)
        .handler(
            new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
              @Override
              protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                ch.pipeline().addLast(new io.netty.handler.codec.FixedLengthFrameDecoder(200));
                ch.pipeline().addLast(new ClientHandler());
              }
            }
        );
  }
}
```

**ClientHandler.java**

```
public class ClientHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {
  private final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ClientHandler.class.getSimpleName());
  @Override
  public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
    final int MESSAGE_SIZE = 200;
    final int NUMBER_OF_MESSAGES = 200000;
    new Thread(()->{
    ByteBuf buf = createMessage(MESSAGE_SIZE);
    for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_MESSAGES; ++i) {
      ctx.writeAndFlush(buf.retain());
    }}).start();
  }
  int i;
  @Override
  public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
    if(i++%10000==0)
    LOG.info("Got a message back from the server "+(i));
    ((io.netty.util.ReferenceCounted)msg).release();
  }
  @Override
  public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) throws Exception {
    cause.printStackTrace();
    ctx.close();
  }
  private ByteBuf createMessage(int size) {
    ByteBuf message = Unpooled.buffer(size);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
      message.writeByte((byte) i);
    }
    return message;
  }
}
```

**Server.java**

```
public class Server {
  public Server(int port) {
    EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(1);
    EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
    try {
      ChannelFuture channelFuture = createServerBootstrap(bossGroup, workerGroup).bind(port).sync();
      channelFuture.channel().closeFuture().sync();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
      bossGroup.shutdownGracefully();
      workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
    }
  }
  private ServerBootstrap createServerBootstrap(EventLoopGroup bossGroup,
                                                EventLoopGroup workerGroup) {
    return new ServerBootstrap().group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
        .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
        .handler(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO))
        .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
          @Override
          protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
             ch.pipeline().addLast(new io.netty.handler.codec.FixedLengthFrameDecoder(200));
             ch.pipeline().addLast(new ServerHandler());
          }
        });
  }
}
```

**ServerHandler.java**

```
public class ServerHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {
  private final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ServerHandler.class.getSimpleName());
  @Override
  public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
    ctx.writeAndFlush(msg).addListener(f->{if(f.cause()!=null)LOG.info(f.cause().toString());});
    if(i++%10000==0)
    LOG.info("Send the message back to the client "+(i));
    ;
  }
  int i;
  @Override
  public void channelReadComplete(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
   // LOG.info("Send the message back to the client "+(i++));
    ctx.flush();
  }
  @Override
  public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) throws Exception {
    cause.printStackTrace();
    ctx.close();
  }
}
```

### Test results

I decided to test what would happen if I change the frequenty of logged incmoing messages, these are the test results:

```
What to print:                            max message latency    time taken*
(always)                                  > 20000                >10 min        
i++ % 10 == 0                             > 20000                >10 min
i++ % 100 == 0                            16000                    4 min
i++ % 1000 == 0                           0-3000                  51 sec
i++ % 10000 == 0                          <10000                  22 sec
```

<sub>* Time should be taken with a grain of salt, there was no real benchmarking done, only 1 quick shot run of the program</sub>

This shows that by reducing the amount of call to log (precision), we can get better transmission rates (speed).